# Apache: Internal Port Redirecting to Public Port

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, wordpress

So, I'm running Apache on an internal server and I port forwarded, say port 10000 from outside to port 80 internally.

My router doesn't support loopback so I tried accessing it from outside my network.  I went to `<external ip>:10000/wordpress` and I can see the Wordpress login page just fine.

When I tested `<internal ip>:80` on my internal network, I can see the Apache's default "It works!" webpage.  I can even browse around my /var/www/ folder if I give it the right path.  But when I go to `<internal ip>:80/wordpress/`, my browser automatically tries to redirect it to `<internal ip>:10000/wordpress` and it fails.

Why is it mixing up the `<internal ip>` with the `<external port>` and how do I stop it from redirecting?
I should be able to go to `<internal ip>:80` from my internal network and not have it redirect.

Server OS: Ubuntu Server 10.10

Router: Trendnet 652BRP

Answer (score 0):

For testing your port forwarding for a web page I would use [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) and take a picture or 2 of what's seen from the outside. You'll see odd results trying to access the WAN interface from the inside. so it's always good to get a **true** outside perspective.

You are likely receiving the "It Works!" apache default page because of how wordpress was set up. If the install was performed with an automation tool, it may have made a custom rule with `mod_rewrite` or modified your Apache configuration. Double check your `httpd.conf` to see the host configuration for Apache as well as the `Listen` directive.

Comment: I am seeing the "It works" web page when I go to <internal port>:80.  Which is fine because Apache is suppose to run on 80 at the /var/www root.  I have my wordpress installation on /var/www/wordpress and that's the one I am not seeing when I go to <internal port>:80/wordpress because of the redirect.